# In python How do i check whether a string starts with special symbol or not?

Tags: python

I wana check whether my string starts with a curly brace {.
i tried the following code.

```
class parser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fp=open('jsondata.txt','r')
        self.str=self.fp.read()
        print "Name of the file Opened is :",self.fp.name 
        print "Contents of the file :\n",self.str
    def rule1(self):
        var='{'
        if self.str[:0]==var:
            print "good match"
        else:
            print "No match"
obj=parser()
obj.rule1()
```

The file contains: {"name":"Chuvi"}
but my output is: No match

i even tried the following but dint get output

```
            if self.str[:0]=='{':
                print "good match"
            else:
                print "No match"
```

Comment: Since im new to python i wish know the reason. whats wrong in my code?? why can't we check special characters directly??

Comment: Err... Is there any reason you try to write a custom JSON parser when there's one in the standard lib ?

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers : Well i am aware of that library... since im just a beginner, this my task to do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a slice, the end index is exclusive. Therefore, `self.str[:0]` always returns an empty string (it stops just *before* the zeroth character).

The correct way to write that slice is `self.str[:1]`.

A more idiomatic to perform the check is

```
self.str.startswith('{')
```

Comment: @ NPE : Since im new to python i wish know the reason. whats wrong in my code?? why can't we check special characters directly??

Comment: @Chuvi: Please refresh this page and check out the updated answer. It explains what exactly is wrong with the original code.

Answer (score 0):

`[:0]` gives you everything from the start of the string up to (but not including) the 0th character. Hence it will always return '' (the empty string).

You could use `[0]` instead. (i.e. `if self.str[0] == '{'`) This would work, but would raise an exception if self.str is the empty string.

So try `[:1]` instead, which will get you the first character if one exists, or will give you '' if str is empty.

An alternative is to use `if self.str.startswith('{')`. This will also do the right thing even if `self.string` is an empty string.

Comment: `[0]` would raise an exception if the string is empty.

Comment: Yeah, good call. I realised that but thought I wouldn't go down he rabbit hole, but you're right, what I wrote is unhelpful for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `startswith` method

```
>>> "{a".startswith('{')
True
>>> "".startswith('{')
False
>>> "Fun".startswith('{')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
class parser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fp=open('jsondata.txt','r')
        self.str=self.fp.read()
        print "Name of the file Opened is :",self.fp.name 
        print "Contents of the file :\n",self.str
    def rule1(self):
        var='{'
        if self.str[0]==var:
            print "good match"
        else:
            print "No match"
obj=parser()
obj.rule1()
```